# A xmlns:android, how does that actually work?

Tags: android, xml

Consider the following perfectly well formed layout file on android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, PurpleActivity"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I looked at this and got curious about that ULR: http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android. So, I tried to enter it into my web browser's address bar and also tried to fetch it via CURL, but both methods showed that it doesn't actually exist. I looked for something akin to an apk/res/android directory in the android-sdk folder on my local machine, but that searched turned up nothing as well. So, I figured since this resource didn't actually exist, maybe that I could change the xmlns:android line to whatever I wanted. I went ahead and changed it to

```
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/androidASDFASDFASDFASDFLKJSDFLEIE
```

and then tried to recompile my project. I got this result:

```
-resource-src:
     [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...
     [aapt]     (skipping hidden file '/Users/rutski/Desktop/purple/res/layout/.#main.xml')
     [aapt] /Users/rutski/Desktop/purple/res/layout/main.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'orientation' in package 'androidASDFASDFASDFASDFLKJSDFLEIE'
     [aapt] /Users/rutski/Desktop/purple/res/layout/main.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'androidASDFASDFASDFASDFLKJSDFLEIE'
     [aapt] /Users/rutski/Desktop/purple/res/layout/main.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_height' in package 'androidASDFASDFASDFASDFLKJSDFLEIE'
     [aapt] /Users/rutski/Desktop/purple/res/layout/main.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'androidASDFASDFASDFASDFLKJSDFLEIE'
     [aapt] /Users/rutski/Desktop/purple/res/layout/main.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_height' in package 'androidASDFASDFASDFASDFLKJSDFLEIE'
     [aapt] /Users/rutski/Desktop/purple/res/layout/main.xml:7: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'text' in package 'androidASDFASDFASDFASDFLKJSDFLEIE'
```

This leaves me confused. If the resource doesn't exist anyway, then what does it matter if I change the xmlns:android value to some other nonexistent resource? And if it does exist, then where is it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace

Answer (score 7):

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` declares an XML namespace prefix. `xmlns` indicates it's about a namespace declaration. `android` is the prefix. `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` is a URI - a string that uniquely identifies which namespace is referred to. The URI can be something abstract (as in this case); it is not necessarily a URL that physically locates something.

In general, you are free to choose the actual prefix. You can most likely replace `android` with something else and it will still work.

So what that attribute actually means is "We need to work with nodes from the namespace `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` here, and in this file, we're going to refer to that namespace as `android`.

If, in several files, you define different namespace prefixes using the same URI, all those files will be referring to the same namespace - because the URI is the same. The prefix can be seen a a shorthand notation for referring to the actual namespace. The prefix can only be used inside the file that defines it.

Comment: You said that the attribute means: "We need to work with nodes from the namespace http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android." But that doesn't explain where it is defined what set of nodes live in that namespace to begin with. And that's what I'm primarily confused about.

Comment: From a pure XML point of view, the URI need not refer to anything that exists anywhere. You could write xmlns:rutski="www.rutski.com" and the file would be ok as far as XML is concerned. The presence of the namespace allows you to place nodes in it. E.g. android:orientation="vertical" puts the orientation attribute in the android namespace. This becomes relevant when the file is processed by other software, e.g. validated against a schema. The schema will be defined as expecting the nodes in the XML file to reside in a given namespace, which will be http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.

Comment: Not that there actually is such a schema as far as I can tell. Basically the point is that Android expects you to place your nodes in that namespace. To what extent any further processing checks/requires that is entirely up to Android.

Comment: "nodes from the namespace" - what does that mean ? I looked it up, but did not understand it fully - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespaces_in_APIs_and_XML_object_models

Comment: When validating an XML instance against a schema, the XML instance refers to a schema file, which defines the validity rules. The schema file in turn defines a target namespace. The XML instance will only be considered as valid if its nodes reside in that target namespace. That's what I was referring to by the nodes "being from the [android] namespace".

Comment: @Dabbler - I am new to XML and I am not able to understand what you said, there is a lot of jargon in that. Please have a look at the follow up question i have posted - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771004/understanding-xmlnsandroid-url-based-on-an-old-so-post

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not a resource, it's just a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI). Usually, processes that work with XML files expect a specific XML namespace. When you use your namespace, it's as if you renamed the attributes to something else. And so the tools that work with them don't recognize them anymore.