# Understanding xmlns:android = URL ? (Based on an old SO post)

Tags: android, xml

I looked at this old question to understand the xmlns:android thing, here 
[A xmlns:android, how does that actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704759/a-xmlnsandroid-how-does-that-actually-work)

I am new to XML and Android, so I could not understand the comment and I need help for that. Here is the comment -

From a pure XML point of view, the URI need not refer to anything that exists anywhere. You could write xmlns:rutski="www.rutski.com" and the file would be ok as far as XML is concerned. The presence of the namespace allows you to place nodes in it. E.g. android:orientation="vertical" puts the orientation attribute in the android namespace. This becomes relevant when the file is processed by other software, e.g. validated against a schema. The schema will be defined as expecting the nodes in the XML file to reside in a given namespace, which will be schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.

```
1 - What exactly are these nodes and how does life become better by using them ?
    In the above comment, where is the node located ? 
2 - What would the xml look like if we did not use namespace ?
```